# Alternative to std::set (with ability to move elements from one set to another)

Tags: c++, stl, set

I'm looking for an alternative to `std::set`. I need it to support more operations then `std::set`:

1. Move elements from one set to another without '*create new->copy->remove old*'.
2. Split set at some position to get two sets (similar behaviour can be obtained using `std::list splice`)
3. Set operations (like union) without unnecessary copying. `std::set_union` will copy elements from sets A and B to set C which is inefficient if I only need set C and don't need A and B anymore.

Are there any implementations which support these operations or I need to write one myself?

Comment: What you want isn’t an alternative to `std::set`, but simply more algorithms working on sets. Thanks to the design of the C++ containers & algorithms library that’s entirely transparent. You can add the algorithms without having to change the data structure. As for point one, you can use `std::move`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, `set` iterators are const to prevent you invalidating keys. If the moved-from element changed value (which is likely) its position in the set would need to change. You'd need to be **very** careful to move the element, then immediately erase it via the iterator, so that nothing inspects the value after it's been moved

Comment: Oops, I meant to say "Even if you cast away the const you'd need to be **very** careful ..."

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well, “move, then erase” was actually implied in my answer because obviously that element isn’t valid any more.

Comment: But not just `erase(key)` it must be `erase(iter)` because the former tries to find the element, and searching the `set` while the ordering invariant is broken would not work. Basically it's in the realms of undefined behaviour

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Even with `std::move` tree nodes will need to be allocated and removed.

Comment: @Simon Well, no method could prevent *that*. Even if you had a means of taking the actual node from one set and inserting into the other you most probably wouldn’t gain anything in terms of speed because you’d save one measly allocation but you’d still have to change all the pointers and tree structure.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem as you with `std::set` and there doesn't seem to be any sane way around with C++11, C++14. However in C++17 there are two new members added to `std::set` which look very promising.
`std::set::extract` allows extracting an entire node from the set. The removed node allows for obtaining a non-const reference to the underlying value effectively allowing for moving elements out of the set. It can be also inserted into another set without copying or moving the underlying value. `std::set::merge` allows for merging two sets without copying or moving any elements, only updating internal pointers.

Answer (score 2):

For point 1 & 3, you can use `set<shared_ptr>` or some other smart pointer instead of store object directly in the `set`. In this case, you should implement

```
bool operator<(shared_ptr<T> const & a, shared_ptr<T> const & b)
```

For point 2, there won't be such a method determined just by index because there's no index in `set`. However, you can use something like `filter` in ruby. Here predicator can be function, function object or closure.

```
remove_copy_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(), back_inserter(bar), some_predicator);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with trying to do what you suggest with a `std::set` is that I do not believe you can move a value out of one. This is due to set iterators only returning const references to stop you changing the value and breaking the internal structure. You could probably `const_cast` your way around this but I wouldn't recommend it. Even if you adopt this approach then you still have nodes in the tree being allocated and there is nothing you can do to avoid this overhead.

If you decide to implement your own set which supports moving values around, you should be able to get the Boost::Intrusive library (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/intrusive.html) to do the heavy lifting of keeping a set of sorted values. You would need to implement the code for managing the object lifetimes but that is easier than building a RB-tree implementation.

I implemented something similar for maps which stored the nodes in a `std::list`. This allowed for moving elements between maps without copying either the node structure or the values being stored.  If I get time I will try and tidy it up and post it here.